# Windows 8 dev possible with native c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-8, microsoft-metro

**Can you make metro apps for windows 8 with using only c++?** I mean, without all those windows compiler specific extension like gc and all that. I've tried search some code for windows 8 dev, and every code example for c++ uses all those rather useless windows c++ extensions.

Comment: "rather useless windows c++ extensions" I'm curious; what exactly is "rather useless" about them? Considering the amount of COM setup code they hide, they can be quite useful for their intended purpose.

Comment: C++/CX is not C++/CLI and does not have a gc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is essentially about whether you have to use C++/CX extensions to write Metro applications.

No, you do not *have* to; all of the language extension have in-language analogs. You can think of the C++/CX extensions to be like Qt's pre-processor setup magic. All of the C++/CX extensions have equivalent pure C++ analogs. You *could* write it all out explicitly.

You just don't really *want* to. Metro APIs are based on COM objects and so forth. So you will have to explicitly deal with COM interfaces, marshalling, and so forth.

Either way, you're writing code that's only going to work on Windows. So you may as well make it easy on yourself and just use the language extensions where necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this answer did help with couple of things related to Metro apps!

Comment: If it's just hiding COM, then why not use ATL?

Comment: Even using ATL, the code would still look tedious. And of course you can use it, there is a library called Windows Runtime C++ Template Library
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466%28v=vs.110%29

Comment: +1 on the above - windows runtime programming using the low level C++ language projection is really ugly.

Answer (score 1):

WinRT apps require Windows specific extensions because they run in a sandbox environemnt. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974580.aspx. You can use WinRT APIs with C++, C#, and JavaScript.

It require Visual Studios (latest).

Comment: So why does all those examples use c++ windows specific extensions? e.g partial ref class MainPage : public Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page

Comment: It is a special Windows API and environment; thus it requires specific Windows code.

Comment: So it means that you can't use plain ISO c++ for windows 8 dev, but you need to use those useless language features?

Comment: If you want to make a Metro App for the Windows Store, you have to use the sandbox environment and other API features required for all apps. You can still make normal c++ apps, but not Metro ones.